# How can I store Date and Time in SQLite Database when I pick date and time via date picker and time picker?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datetime, datepicker

I am implementing `date picker` and `time picker` functionality after pick date and time I want to store it in `SQLite` ?

Currently I am storing Date and Time using getting value from edit text box and convert into String and Save into `SQLite`.

Is this right way to store date and time like this ?

```
 EditText Reminder_Time,Followup_date;

  Reminder_Time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(Activity_Add_Followup.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    Reminder_Time.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                }
            }, hour, minute, false);
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();
            Reminder_Time.setEnabled(true);
        }


    });
     Followup_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             new DatePickerDialog(Activity_Add_Followup.this, date, myCalendar
                     .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                     myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

             Followup_date.setEnabled(true);
         }
     });

final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel();
    }

};



private void updateLabel() {
    String myFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

    Followup_date.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

No errors.

Comment: The best way is to store the dates as a number

Comment: When I am showing date on text view it is showing in ```yyyy/mm/dd``` and I want to change the format in ```dd/mm/yyyy```.

Comment: Using `yyyy-mm-dd` or another format understood by sqlite [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) in the DB is going to work out much better. You can use `strftime()` to format it differently for display purposes.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not a good practice to store dates as Strings due to a number of reasons**. e.g: If you want to run a Query to sort your data based on dates you could just go "ORDER BY date" if you stored it properly, but keeping Strings wont allow this. A more detailed explanation can be found here : [Why you shouldnt keep dates as Strings in Database](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331653/why-not-return-dates-as-a-string-from-the-database/331654)

So, a much better way to keep dates would be:

**If you are using ROOM**

For the Entity Classes keep date as java.util.Date type. Like below:

```
@Entity(tableName = NoteConstants.TABLE_NAME)
public class Note {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = NoteConstants.ATTR_ID)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = NoteConstants.ATTR_DESCRIPTION)
    private String description;

    @ColumnInfo(name = NoteConstants.ATTR_DATE)
    private Date date;

    public Note(String description) { 
        this.description = description;
        this.date = new Date();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

Now We need to define a typeConverter for Java's Date type which ROOM will use:

```
import androidx.room.TypeConverter;

import java.util.Date;

public class DateConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static long toTimeStamp(Date date){
        return date == null? null : date.getTime();
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(Long timeStamp){
        return timeStamp == null ? null : new Date(timeStamp);
    }

}
```

finally, we need to specify the type converters in the ROOM @Database class using @TypeConverters:

```
@Database(entities = {Note.class}, version = 1) 
@TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
public abstract class NoteDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static String DB_NAME = "note_database";
    private static NoteDatabase instance;

    public abstract NoteDAO getNoteDao();

    public static synchronized NoteDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    NoteDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration() 
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

**If you are not using ROOM and using raw SQLite openHelper:**

Just keep the long timestamp in the database and use the type conversion methods we built above manually to get the Date from the long timestamp and vice versa.

Comment: Then all you need is to use the DateConverter class methods manually. Before storing date into database convert it into long timeStamp using the toTimeStamp() method and store the timeStamp and similarly after fetching the long from the database use the toDate() method to convert it into a java.util.Date. Since you are using Calender here, you can call Date date = calendar.getTime() to get the java.util.Date type object from the Calender

Comment: is there is any problem to store date in string ?

Comment: That is actually not a good practice. A very good explanation can be found here, hope this helps : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331653/why-not-return-dates-as-a-string-from-the-database/331654