# Parse the String to Date and format

Tags: android, android-date

In the fragment I have a DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener. If I choose a Date, I send it to the presenter in the form of a String. Then I want to parse String to Date in Presenter and before save in the database change the format of Date.

SavePresenter:

```
 @Override
public void addTaskClick(String text, String date, String time, boolean status) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    Date updateDate = null;
    try {
        updateDate = format.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("Save Presenter", updateDate.);
    realmService.addTask(text, updateDate, time, status, this);
}
```

This is what I have now: E/Save Presenter: Tue Dec 17 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019
I want to have this: 17 12 2019
Or something similar. I need it to compare saved dates with current date to sort tasks by date.
I also tried the DateFormat but the result was the same.

Comment: Dont keep dates as strings in the database, keep a long timestamp. A Simple database order_by would give u a sorting based on date if u keep a long timestamp, so no need to write any additional comparator/comparable for sorting stuff by date. Answer in this question uses room (not realm) but still it should give u a good idea on exactly what you need to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247286/how-can-i-store-date-and-time-in-sqlite-database-when-i-pick-date-and-time-via-d/58247418#58247418

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you for the interesting lesson.

Comment: @schrodingers_cat16 What if I need to compare for example days? I mean: If I save date by DatePicker there is day, month, year and others, but without the time and then I want compare this with current date and there is time? How to get timestamp from the database and receive a day or month but no time?

Comment: You can always convert a long time stamp into a date with day, month, year using new Date(timestamp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");` won't do the trick try instead `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T' HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");`

[image]

you need to specify the date on the required formats

Taken from [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat)

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing the date into another `Date`. Parse it into `String` and then check the log. You should be seeing the desired output.

Comment: But I need it as a date, not a string. In string I can't take tasks from the database by date. If I want to take all of tomorrow's tasks in string case I can't.

Comment: I believe that when you printing `updateDate` it is giving you the right result. If you notice, you are getting the same output as you desire. Later when you compare the `updateDate`, it will give you the desired output.

Comment: No, because if I create today's task, in logs I see date together with time, which I don't need it. I need compare days not time.

Answer (score 0):

`Log.e("Save Presenter", format.format(updateDate));`

will print the Date to log in desired format. 
Is this what you wanted?